# Selenium - Web driver code is not working after restarting the system

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I  installed eclipse to work with Selenium, my code was running successfully until I restarted my system. After restarting the system and running the existing code which was save before restarting the system, it is running successfully, but `Editor does not contain main type` message is displayed after changing the existing code with the below simple code, could anybody please help

**Code:**

```java
    package newpackage; 
    import org.openqa.selenium.*; 
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
    import java.util.List; 
    import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    
    public class MyClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    
    String tagName = driver.findElement(By.id("email")).getTagName();
    
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117713/editor-does-not-contain-a-main-type-in-eclipse

Comment: Did you try all these ?

Comment: I would suggest simply creating a makefile with the necessary commands rather than relying on error-prone and confusing IDE UI's to set up your runs. OSs don't run programs through UIs.

Comment: @JoãoFarias what is a makefile?

Comment: It's the script file format for Unix's Make build tool. There are plenty of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try any or all of the below mentioned points to check and resolve the issue.

1. Check if your project is a **Java Project** and not a **General Project**.
2. Ensure that your class file (.java file) is inside the **src** folder.
3. Verify that your folder in which the code (.java) is written is identified as source folder.

3.1 Got to **Properties** by right clicking on the project folder.

3.2 Choose **Java Build Path**.

3.3 Click on **Sources** tab.

3.4 Click on **Add Folder** on the right panel.

3.5 Select your folders and click Apply to save the changes.

4. Clean Up and Refresh your project in Eclipse.

4.1 Right click on project folder.

4.2 Point cursor to **Source** and then click **Clean Up**.

4.3 Click Next and then Finish in the clean up window.

4.4 Again right click on project folder and then select **Refresh**.

5. In your class/code remove the line `public static void main(String args[])` and save the code. Then again add the line and save the project and repeat steps in point 4.